# Type definition: expected UnionAll, got TypeVar

Tags: types, julia

In the Julia manual for v0.6 I find the following:

```
abstract type Pointy{T} end
struct Point{T} <: Pointy{T}
    x::T
    y::T
end
```

This works fine, and I thought the following should as well:

```
abstract type Foo{V, F} end
struct Bar{V, F} <: Foo{V, F}
    x::V{F}
end
```

The definition of `Bar` gives, however, the following error

```
ERROR: TypeError: Type{...} expression: expected UnionAll, got TypeVar
```

What is wrong, and how can I achieve what I really want, namely to specify that `V<:AbstractVector` and `F<:AbstractFloat`?

Comment: What solved my problem was changing `Vector{...}` to `Array{..., 1}`.

Comment: Hmm, it probably had something to do with the fact that I overrode or shadowed `Vector`...

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
julia> abstract type Foo{T} end

julia> struct Bar{T<:AbstractFloat,V<:AbstractVector{T}} <: Foo{T}
           x::V
       end

julia> Bar{T}(v::AbstractVector{T}) = Bar{T,typeof(v)}(v) # constructor
Bar

julia> Bar(rand(3))
Bar{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}([0.387467, 0.535419, 0.240748])

julia> Bar(rand(Int, 3))
ERROR: TypeError: Bar: in T, expected T<:AbstractFloat, got Type{Int64}
Stacktrace:
 [1] Bar(::Array{Int64,1}) at ./REPL[4]:1
```

Comment: Great! This works. Do you know what was wrong with my first approach? I expected to have to sprinkle some `where`'s over it, but I couldn't figure out where to put them.

Comment: Should the constructor perhaps be an inner constructor in this case?

Comment: Ah, I guess that is what Dan Getz version does

Answer (score 4):

Another option (got it to work concurrently with @tholy's answer and uses the same route of having V "include" the parameter F). To get it to work nicely, an external constructor should be added, like @tholy's answer (maybe this was a bit redundant, but it uses the `where` syntax)

```
struct Bar{V, F} <: Foo{V,F}
    x::V
    Bar{V,F}(x::V) where {F, V<:AbstractVector{F}} = new(x)
end
```

and this works like so:

```
julia> Bar{Vector{Int},Int}([1,2,3])
Bar{Array{Int64,1},Int64}([1, 2, 3])

julia> Bar{Vector{Int},Float64}([1,2,3])
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Array{Int64,1} to an object of type Bar{Array{Int64,1},Float64}
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Bar{Array{Int64,1},Float64}(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
```

Comment: Right, that works too. A distinction between the solutions is that your version uses the *constructor* to enforce constraints on the parameters, whereas mine enforces it in the type itself.

Comment: With respect to the title of my question: "expected UnionAll, got TypeVar". Do you happen to know what that means?

Comment: Not the expert on the type system, but `V{F}` is not allowed. `V` and `F` are TypeVars (i.e. parameters) and instead of `V` the parser wants a `UnionAll` which is a collection of types, like `Array` or `Vector`. The name `UnionAll` is from Array representing the union of all Array{T,N} types or in `where` syntax: `Array{T,N} where {T,N}`. Specifically, the following hold in the REPL: `isa(Array,UnionAll) == true` and `Array == (Array{T,N} where {T,N}) == true`. If there is a good lookup reference, please add it in a comment (or I shall do it, or someone else)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answers of @tholy and @DanGetz I messed about a bit and came up with an answer I liked:

```
abstract type Foo{V} end
struct Bar{V <: AbstractVector{<:AbstractFloat}} <: Foo{V}
    x::V
end

julia> Bar(rand(5))
Bar{Array{Float64,1}}([0.722314, 0.159418, 0.13561, 0.288794, 0.347009])

julia> Bar(2.0:5.0)
Bar{StepRangeLen{Float64,Base.TwicePrecision{Float64},Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}}}(2.0:1.0:5.0)

julia> Bar(2:5)
ERROR: MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type UnitRange{Int64} to an object of type Bar
```

I like this because it seems simpler, the default constructor works directly, and I don't get "doubling" of the floating point typevar, that is, `Bar{Array{Float64,1}}` instead of `Bar{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}`.

Not sure if there are any drawbacks to this version, though. Also, I still don't understand why some of my efforts work and some fail with syntax or other errors.