# Type parameters and inner constructors in julia 0.6

Tags: julia

I am in doubt about how to restrict type parameters for parametric types with abstract types in julia 0.6, using the `where` syntax.

Consider the example where I want to make a parametric abstract type that takes integers, and define structs inheriting from that. If I try:

```
abstract type AbstractFoo{T} where T<: Integer end
```

it fails, but instead I can use the non-`where` syntax

```
abstract type AbstractFoo{T<:Integer} end
```

1. Is this the recommended format?

Given this, how do I implement my subtype

```
mutable struct Foo{T} <: AbstractFoo{T} where T <: Integer
   bar::T
end
```

fails too (`Invalid subtyping`). I can bypass the `where` syntax again with

```
mutable struct Foo{T<:Integer} <: AbstractFoo{T}
   bar::T
end
```

But that seems to be redundant (because T is already restricted to be an Integer). 2. Could I leave it out?:

```
mutable struct Foo{T} <: AbstractFoo{T}
    bar::T
end
```

Finally, with the deprecation of inner constructor syntax, is there any way around defining the inner constructor as:

```
mutable struct Foo{T} <: AbstractFoo{T}
    bar::T
    Foo{T}(x::T) where T = new(x)
end
```

This makes `Foo(3)` impossible - requiring me to use `Foo{Int}(3)`. 3. Is this intentional or is there a better way around this?
EDIT: I guess for the inner constructor question I can always define an outer constructor `Foo(x::T) where {T} = Foo{T}(x)`.

Comment: To give context to the question, my (unpublished) package is experiencing a factor-10 performance regression on Julia-0.6 presently, and I suspect this may be due to type instabilities caused by problematic parametric type definitions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would write:

```
abstract type AbstractFoo{T<:Integer} end

mutable struct Foo{T} <: AbstractFoo{T}
    bar::T
    Foo(x::T) where T = new{T}(x)
end
```

this 1) limit x to `Integer` 2) allow write `Foo(2)`

About the questions:

1. yes, that the right and only right format
2. that's valid and T will be restrict to `Integer`, but you may get a worse error message since it is arised from `AbstractFoo`, not `Foo`. Your user may not notice that `Foo` is a subtype of `AbstractFoo` and get confused.
3. This is intended and is one of the main purposes of introducing `where` syntax. In the new syntax, `T{S}` always specify the type parameter of `T` and `where S` is introducing type parameter of the function. So `Foo{T}(x) where T =` defines what `Foo{Int}(2)` should do, and `Foo(x::T) where T =` defines what `Foo(2)` should do. After `where` was introduced, there are no "inner constructor" anymore. You can define any function inside any struct (not necessarily constructors of that type), and define any constructor outside type definition - the only difference is inside type definition, you have access of `new`.

Comment: here, is there any advantage of using [Outer-only constructors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/constructors.html#Outer-only-constructors-1) instead of the default inner-outer constructor pairs? also can you elaborate more about "After where was introduced, there are no "inner constructor" anymore."?

Comment: Thanks, I'll follow this advice :-)

Comment: @Gnimuc umm, actually there are still inner constructors, but they are not the same as the one before. There are no special treating for type parameters of constructors, they are the same as other normal functions. Before `where` was introduced, `Foo(x::T)=` inside a type definition actually defines constructors for `Foo{T}`, but outside type definition it defines constructors for `Foo`. After `where` was introduced, there are no such difference.  `Foo{T}(x)=` always define constructors for `Foo{T}` and `Foo(x)=` defines `Foo` no matter where they are.

Comment: Using Outer-only constructors here is just to mimic the behavior in the question. Of course for this example the better option would be using the default inner constructor and add `Foo(x::T) where T = Foo{T}(x)` outside the type definition.

Comment: @张实唯 @Michael K. Borregaard Note that, using `Foo(x::T) where T = new{T}(x)`, users cannot run `Foo{Int}(2)` as before(with the default inner constructor that Julia automatically defined for you). I don't think this is the right way/case to use outer-only constructors.

Comment: Ah, the plot thickens. But what is the right way of doing the constructor here then? I should note that this is an MWE - in my actual code example, the inner constructor is used to ensure that some constraints on the fields are met (e.g. I have a vector and a Matrix, and the Vector needs to be the same length as one dim of the Matrix).

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard as you wrote in the original post, manually defining the corresponding outer constructor is the typical way. Indeed, outer-only constructors do have their use-cases -- prevent users from using inner constructors.

Answer (score 2):

I am on slightly shaky ground here, but I had a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178425/type-definition-expected-unionall-got-typevar) question not long ago. Based on what I learned from that, I suggest that you try this and see how it works for you:

```
abstract type AbstractFoo{T} end

mutable struct Foo{T<:Integer} <: AbstractFoo{T}
    bar::T
end
```

It seems most reasonable to me to restrict the parameter on the concrete type rather than on the abstract one.

Comment: Thanks for the response! :-). Still - I'd really like to know what the intended/ideomatic usage is. I've experimented with various versions that don't error (including this one), but still I am seeing a performance regression (and what looks like more problematic outputs from @code_warntype). Also, my AbstractFoo will ever only have subtypes where T is an Integer, so you could argue for the point in restricting the type parameter there. Finally, the inner constructor is also tricky.